# How to find the term of $x^3$ in $(1+x)^5(1-x+x^2)^4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, binomial-theorem

How to find the term of $x^3$ in $$(1+x)^5(1-x+x^2)^4?$$ I have been trying a few shortcuts but are useless, can anyone teach me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use $$x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I did it! :)

Comment: @Nicholas Teoh You are welcome!